# Code and encode UIView and UIViewController

Tags: ios, encoding, uiview, decoding

Good day, everyone!

I have some view in scrollView. I want to save that views into file and then when app is open load it. So i have thias code:

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)_coder{
    [_coder encodeObject:self.currentForecast forKey:@"currentForecast"];
    [_coder encodeObject:self.weatherForecastView forKey:@"weatherForecastView"];
    [_coder encodeObject:self forKey:@"self"];
    [_coder encodeObject:self.view forKey:@"view"];
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.currentForecast     = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"currentForecast"];
        self.weatherForecastView = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"weatherForecastView"];
        self.view                = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"view"];
        self                     = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"self"];
    }
    return self; 

}
```

it works, but it looks like a screenshot of the views. How to live them up?

Answer (score 0):

*If it works*, then why not just simplify like the following (remove the `retain` if you use ARC):

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)_coder{
    [_coder encodeObject:self forKey:@"self"];
}

-(instanceType) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"self"] retain];
    return self; 
}
```

But I don't think it really works because using `initWithCoder` for `self` prevents calling `[self init]`. Or you can try:

```
-(instanceType) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"self"] init];
    return self; 
}
```

But what is more common is to not encode `self` and that means:

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)_coder{
    [_coder encodeObject:self.view forKey:@"view"];
    ...
}

-(instanceType) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self)
        return nil;
    self.view = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"view"];
    ...
    return self; 
}
```